# Move git configuration from Windows to Ubuntu

Tags: git, ubuntu, github, ssh-keys

I recently started using git on windows 7 and configured everything to access Github, Bitbucket and a private server over ssh.

Now I am switching to Ubuntu OS and I am not sure how to copy the keys and configuration settings over to Ubuntu.

Will you please help me out or point me in the direction of how to do it right ?

Comment: Not to put you off, but is there a reason why you cannot simply reconfigure your Ubuntu box from scratch?

Comment: Hi Tim, It is because I am not well versed with how ssh keys work. If i'll setup everything from scratch on Ubuntu including generating new keys does that mean I'll have to add these new keys to github and that private server as well. May be because the contents of the keys differ and it is a separate new key pair authentication.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

To build upon [Hi-Angel's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30658561/1734119):

### Under Windows 7

- The local Git config is inside the `.git` directory at the root of your repository/project.
- The global Git settings are in `C:\Users\<user_name>\.gitconfig`.
- The SSH keys you generated are in `C:\Users\<user_name>\.ssh` (at least, this is the standard).

### Under Ubuntu/Linux

- The local Git config is inside the `.git` directory at the root of your repository/project (no change and no work here).
- The global Git settings are in `~/.gitconfig`.
- The SSH keys you generated are in `~/.ssh` (at least, this is the standard).

### Doing the switch

Copy your `.gitconfig` and `.ssh` folders from one to the other and you should be good to go.

If you configured some things specific to your OS (such as default editors), you will have to configure those again or reset them after performing the copy, but this cannot be avoided.

#### Just a note about SSH and security

You may consider it a hassle, but if one of your computers is a laptop, I would recommend configure separate SSH keys. That way, if your laptop ever gets stolen, you can remove the key and this laptop will never be able to mess with your central repository.

It may not seem that important for codes, but if you use SSH for other purposes (like administering your private server), I think it is crucial to be able to select which computers are allowed to connect.

Comment: Thank You. It worked. :)
I’ll have to reset a few things (default editor etc.) in global .gitconfig file.

Comment: @user1197736 Ah, right. I added a note about this ine the answer, thanks for highlighting it. :)

Answer (score 1):

Local setting are being stored in the root of you project directory with the name of the dir `.git`. But since the project you may probably download from an internet, so the `.git` directory appears automagically, I guess you wanted global settings.

The directory of the global settings in Windows® is `C:\Users\<user_name>\.gitconfig`. In GNU/Linux it is `~/.gitconfig`, so you may just copy a content there.

Comment: You forget to mention the `.ssh` folder, so that there is no need to re-generate the SSH keys. ;)

Comment: @Chop ah, indeed, I forgot this because of the title ☺

Comment: Thank YOu Hi-Angel. Answer added by chop on top of your answer worked for me.

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend to simply copy the ssh public key of your new ubuntu machine into the github account. And the of course, clone the repo again on ubuntu to your favorite local folder

You could use my blog http://balajikatika-technical.blogspot.com/2014/10/setting-up-ssh-keys.html on how to setup ssh keys on a Linux machine. After that you could copy the public key (by default located in /.ssh/id_*.pub file into your github account (Settings->SSH Keys)

Comment: Thank you Balaji. I wanted to avoid copying the key to private server once again

Answer (score 0):

I think the simplest way is to copy the project folder with .git to your Ubuntu and generate new ssh keys for your new computer.

Follow these links below to generate new ssh keys for your new computer and add to the git service. And then everything is done.

- https://help.github.com/articles/generating-ssh-keys/
- https://confluence.atlassian.com/display/BITBUCKET/Set+up+SSH+for+Git
- http://doc.gitlab.com/ce/ssh/README.html

Comment: I actually wanted to generating new ssh keys as then I’d have to copy the new keys to github and the private server. I should have stated this in my question. Thank you.